# How to change a word in a file with linux shell script

Tags: linux, shell, text-files

I have a text file which have lots of lines
I have a line in it which is:
MyCar on

how can I turn my car off?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use sed:

```
sed -i 's/MyCar on/MyCar off/' path/to/file
```

Comment: I read about sed but it was so hard to understand specially for a non-english man.

Comment: @BehnamSafari, don't worry, it's hard to use for people who have English as their first language too.  If you can speak line-noise, you're way ahead of the curve.  (But seriously, [sed is awesome](http://www.kernelthread.com/projects/obfuscation/sedhanoi/).)

Comment: @ghoti: **So true!**. FWIW, your link is dead, but here's a [great intro to `sed`.](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-use-sed-to-find-and-replace-text-in-files-in-linux-unix-shell/)

Comment: @Seamus, ah well, it's 8+ years since I posted that comment; one has to expect some churn. Thanks for posting that intro. Here's a link to the last capture of [Towers of Hanoi](https://web.archive.org/web/20180924033746/http://www.kernelthread.com/projects/obfuscation/sedhanoi/)

Comment: @ghoti: Yes - SO is becoming like a museum.  I wonder what the average life expectancy of a URL is these days? The Towers of Hanoi was fascinating! I didn't know it was called by that name. I got one as a birthday gift when I was a small child - 5 or 6 yo I think... but it was made of wood instead of sed :)

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/MyCar on/MyCar off/' >filename
```

[more on sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed#Usage)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with shell only.  This example uses an unnecessary case statement for this particular example, but I included it to show how you could incorporate multiple replacements.  Although the code is larger than a sed 1-liner it is typically much faster since it uses only shell builtins (as much as 20x for small files).

```
REPLACEOLD="old"
WITHNEW="new"
FILE="tmpfile"
OUTPUT=""
while read LINE || [ "$LINE" ]; do
    case "$LINE" in
        *${REPLACEOLD}*)OUTPUT="${OUTPUT}${LINE//$REPLACEOLD/$WITHNEW}
";;
        *)OUTPUT="${OUTPUT}${LINE}
";;
    esac
done < "${FILE}"
printf "${OUTPUT}" > "${FILE}"
```

for the simple case one could omit the case statement:

```
while read LINE || [ "$LINE" ]; do
    OUTPUT="${OUTPUT}${LINE//$REPLACEOLD/$WITHNEW}
"; done < "${FILE}"
printf "${OUTPUT}" > "${FILE}"
```

Note: the ...|| [ "$LINE" ]... bit is to prevent losing the last line of a file that doesn't end in a new line
(now you know at least one reasone why your text editor keeps adding those)

Answer (score 0):

try this command when inside the file

`:%s/old test/new text/g`

Answer (score 0):

Using sed with variables;

```
host=$(hostname)
se1=$(cat /opt/splunkforwarder/etc/system/local/server.conf | grep serverName)
sed -i "s/${se1}/serverName = ${host}/g"  /opt/splunkforwarder/etc/system/local/server.conf`
```